# MariaDB Installation RPM cyclic reference

Tags: installation, mariadb, rpm

MariaDB common and compat RPM cyclic reference

```
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.1.14-centos6-x86_64-common.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        MariaDB-compat is needed by MariaDB-common-10.1.14-1.el6.x86_64
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.1.14-centos6-x86_64-compat.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        MariaDB-common is needed by MariaDB-compat-10.1.14-1.el6.x86_64
```

common says it needs compat and compat says commmon is needed, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: did you try my solution? Did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; installing both together:

```
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.1.14-centos6-x86_64-common.rpm MariaDB-10.1.14-centos6-x86_64-compat.rpm
```